# Column name characters separated by commas after pandas read_sql. (There is a comma after every character in 1 single column name)

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to create a dataframe after pulling data from my db with pandas:

```
uploaded_files_df = pd.read_sql("""SELECT DISTINCT PRICE_LIST_DT MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE""", conn)
conn.close()
```

It returns the dataframe with the following column name:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 51 entries, 0 to 50
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column                                   Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                                   --------------  -----
 0   (P, R, I, C, E, _, L, I, S, T, _, D, T)  51 non-null     object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 536.0+ bytes
```

I haven't found any guidance in pandas documentation regarding the read_sql function to define separators or something like that.

What I want to achieve is to have the column name like : "PRICE_LIST_DT"
I tried renaming it by:

```
uploaded_files_df = uploaded_files_df.rename(columns={1: 'PRICE_LIST_DT'})
```

but with zero luck.

Comment: I can only answer the renaming part: try `uploaded_files_df.columns=['PRICE_LIST_DT']` or maybe `uploaded_files_df = uploaded_files_df.rename(''.join, axis='columns')`  (you don't have a column with the name `1`, hence your renaming command doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jaydebeapi and jpype to make the connection?
Then **convertStrings** parameter in jpype.startJVM() might help, e.g.:

```
jpype.startJVM(jvm_path, jvmArgs, convertStrings=True)
```

https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#string-conversions